# Why can I use scalar type as the return type of operator->?

Tags: c++

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators):

> The overload of operator `->` must either return a raw pointer, or return an object (by reference or by value) for which operator `->` is in turn overloaded.

However, I tested the following example, and it is accepted by GCC, Clang and MSVC:

```cpp
struct A {
  int operator->();
};
```

According to cppreference, the return type `int` is neither a pointer nor a type that overloads `operator->`.

Why is this example correct? Where is this situation described in the standard? What is the intent of the standard to allow this?

Comment: Have you actually tried using the operator? e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/7WWsf7qe3

Comment: @AlanBirtles It can be called explicitly as `a.operator->()`, and I think the standard allows this. But of course it's pointless.

Comment: *What is the intent of the standard to allow this?*  The standard allows all sorts of nonsense.  There was no reason to disallow it.

Comment: the standard doesn't limit the return type of operator afaict, you can also do `void operator==(const A&);`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, I have tried to do that. But according to cppreference, it seems that the compiler should reject the declaration of that `operator->`.

Comment: @appleapple Thanks. I think this is the correct answer. I just read the standard and the standard does not specify the return type of operator-> .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the standard doesn't directly place restrictions on the return type of `operator->`, it does describe what happens when the overloaded `->` operator is used:

> 12.6.5 Class member access [over.ref]
> A class member access operator function is a function named `operator->` that is a non-static member function taking no parameters. For an expression of the form 
>     `postfix-expression -> template(opt) id-expression`
> the operator function is selected by overload resolution (12.4.1.2), and the expression is interpreted as 
>         `( postfix-expression . operator -> () ) -> template(opt) id-expression`.

So when using your class, you can call the overloaded operator like a normal function by writing `a.operator->()`. But if you attempt to use the operator with `a->name`, this is interpreted as `(a.operator->())->name` which won't compile because it attempts to use `->` on an `int`.